# How to catch the jQuery validation event in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a form that allows a user to enter a value, which should be a number.  I'm using **ValidationMessageFor** to provide validation testing.   I've also added a a function to disable the submit buttons after they are clicked.  If the user enters a text value and then clicks submit, the button is disabled and they can't click it again.

How can I catch the event when the jQuery evaluation occurs, so that I may re-enable the buttons at that time?

```
<script>
    function setOneClick(buttonName) {
        $('[name="' + buttonName + '"]').click(function () {
            console.log("save");
            var self = this;
            setTimeout(function () { $(self).prop('disabled', true); });
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        setOneClick("prevStep");
        setOneClick("saveStep");
        setOneClick("nextStep");
    });
</script>

@Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.Value)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.Value)

@<input type="submit" name="prevStep" value="Previous" />
@<input type="submit" name="saveStep" value="Save" />
@<input type="submit" name="nextStep" value="Next" />

@Section Scripts
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
End Section
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller",
                                   new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST"}, 
                                   new { id = "formId" }))
            {
@Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.Value)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.Value)

  <input type="button" onclick="submitFormDisablebtn()"value="@Resource.Save" class="t-button" id="submitB"/>
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitFormDisablebtn() {
        var validForm = jQuery("#formId").valid(); //if the model will be not valid the 
        //validation messages will be displayed.
        if (validForm == true) {     
            jQuery("#submitB").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            jQuery("#formId").submit();
        }
    }
</script>
```

hope you will understand it and this will help you.